# What is a good wrapper/framework/libraries for dealing with interface PHP applications to an SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, frameworks

I have a table

```
$query=
"CREATE TABLE screenshot ".
"(screenshot_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ".
"source_video_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ".
"screenshot_file_name VARCHAR(128), ".
"x_res INT, ".
"y_res INT, ".
"time INT UNSIGNED);";
mysql_query($query);
```

Then I insert things into that table.

I often want to do an SQL query and iterate over the result of the query, but end up doing this.

```
//select all screenshots from video, by video id
    $q0=
    "SELECT * FROM screenshot ".
    "WHERE source_video_id = '$source_video_id' ".
    "AND x_res = 120 ".
    "AND y_res = 90 ".
    "ORDER BY time ASC;";
    $r0 = mysql_query($q0);
    $n0_num = mysql_numrows($r0);

//for each result
for($n0=0;$n0<$n0_num;$n0++) {
    $source_video_id = mysql_result($r0,$n0,'source_video_id');
    $time = mysql_result($r0,$n0,'time');
    $screenshot_file_name = mysql_result($r0,$n0,'screenshot_file_name');

    //do stuff for each returned result!
}
```

This is just ugly.  To get the SQL query results, I have to write this for every column!
$source_video_id = mysql_result($r0,$n0,'source_video_id');

I have to write an ugly loop, get the results for each row returned and do something for each result.  Basically I want something like;

```
foreach($SQL_command) {
//Do for each result
}
```

I want the column variables for each row to be already set, so that I do not have to do

```
$source_video_id = mysql_result($r0,$n0,'source_video_id');
```

For each and every column I want to access!

I am sick of writing boiler plate code to do this for every single table in my data.  Are there any frameworks or libraries that would make this less painful?

Comment: Assign the result to an array! `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Answer (score 0):

These are the very basics of a [database abstraction layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer). It's not hard to program your own, or you can use a generic library like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/). [Every](http://cakephp.org/) [notable](http://framework.zend.com/) [PHP](http://www.symfony-project.org/) [framework](http://codeigniter.com/) includes some form of database abstraction as well, you really just need to start using one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PDO drivers enabled (as you should) you can use the single `DB()` method as a function from the [**phunction PHP framework**](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/). It was inspired by the [**DiBi** database abstraction layer](http://dibiphp.com/cs/). The documentation is still underway, but [I've posted a short summary in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023818/any-procedural-php-framework-non-oo/3245377#3245377).

```
function DB($query)
{
    static $db = null;
    static $result = array();

    if (is_null($db) === true)
    {
        if (preg_match('~^(?:mysql|pgsql):~', $query) > 0)
        {
            $db = new PDO(preg_replace('~^(mysql|pgsql):(?:/{2})?([-.\w]+)(?::(\d+))?/(\w+)/?$~', '$1:host=$2;port=$3;dbname=$4', $query), func_get_arg(1), func_get_arg(2));

            if (preg_match('~^mysql:~', $query) > 0)
            {
                self::DB('SET time_zone = ?;', 'GMT');
                self::DB('SET NAMES ? COLLATE ?;', 'utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci');
            }
        }

        else if (preg_match('~^(?:sqlite|firebird):~', $query) > 0)
        {
            $db = new PDO(preg_replace('~^(sqlite|firebird):(?:/{2})?(.+)$~', '$1:$2', $query));
        }
    }

    else if (is_a($db, 'PDO') === true)
    {
        if (isset($query) === true)
        {
            $hash = md5($query);

            if (empty($result[$hash]) === true)
            {
                $result[$hash] = $db->prepare($query);
            }

            if (is_a($result[$hash], 'PDOStatement') === true)
            {
                if ($result[$hash]->execute(array_slice(func_get_args(), 1)) === true)
                {
                    if (preg_match('~^(?:INSERT|REPLACE)~i', $query) > 0)
                    {
                        return $db->lastInsertId();
                    }

                    else if (preg_match('~^(?:UPDATE|DELETE)~i', $query) > 0)
                    {
                        return $result[$hash]->rowCount();
                    }

                    else if (preg_match('~^(?:SELECT|EXPLAIN)~i', $query) > 0)
                    {
                        return $result[$hash]->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    return $db;
}
```

Your example query could be written as:

```
// connect to the MySQL server, do this on your config file or something
DB('mysql://host:port/database_name/', 'username', 'password');

// run the query!
$results = DB('SELECT * FROM screenshot WHERE source_video_id = ? AND x_res = ? AND y_res = ? ORDER BY time ASC;', $source_video_id, 120, 90);

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    print_r($result);
}
```

The above code uses prepared queries which means that you'll also be safe from [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).

**PS**: I'm biased here, since I'm the developer of the framework. If you run into any problems let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One can suppose I'm a fan of Kohana, but I really love the thing. Get the [Kohana 3](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/attachments/download/1588/kohana-3.0.7.zip) and put there the [Sprig ORM](http://github.com/banks/sprig) (it's a fork from original Sprig ORM, but with additional ‘sugar’ :) instead of native Kohana's one. You'll understand how pretty they are together. You'll can access to your tables like this code shows:

```
//just the basics, updating existing record
$screenshot = Sprig::factory('Screenshot', $id)->load();
$screenshot->x_res = 240;
$screenshot->y_res = 260;
$screenshot->update();

//creating new one
$screenshot = Sprig::factory('Screenshot');
$screenshot->x_res = 300;
$screenshot->y_res = 250;
$screenshot->create();
```

Additional link to the discussion of the Sprig fork: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=4368

Hope, it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com) in all my projects and would recommend it without hesitation. The main reasons being:

- Minimum configuration required. I don't have to map the database schema into a YAML or JSON file, simply put in the connection parameters and go.
- Elegant and easy to understand usage syntax.
- Lots of features such as caching and tree relationships.
- Pretty good performance.

And here's an example of using it:

```
$book = R::dispense('book');
$book->title = 'Gifted Programmers';
$book->author = 'Charles Xavier';
$id = R::store($book);
```